# Solve for nonlinear problems

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am unable to draw the figure below which is taken from paper.

*However I can draw velocity curves (graphs) using the given code in Mathematica.* using equation 16

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the original pictures in this paper.

Comment: The code works for me. Unless you think there is an error, in which case you should make clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Goofy, The code works well, but my specific question is how to draw Figure 5 using the above code.

Comment: @cvgmt, let me edit the question to add figures.

Comment: @MuhammadMubashirBhatti can you describe your variables more clearly? The plot is for pressure gradient vs `x`. What is pressure in your code? A better understanding of code may help you and us as well.

Comment: @codebpr Thank you for response. Actually in the above mentioned paper we have plotted equation 16, but i don't know how to plot equation (14). The same code will be used.

Comment: @MuhammadMubashirBhatti Sadly, the paper is not publicly available. I cannot see or download it. If possible, you need to elaborate on the details in the question itself.

Comment: @codebpr, can i send you via email? if yes, kindly give me your email. I will send you.

Comment: @MuhammadMubashirBhatti I think it would be better to include the details so that not only me but others who are willing to help can easily understand your problem.

Comment: @codebpr I have added the image of the paper (equations 14-16). I can't add the full paper.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should add the full paper, just the relevant equations and details, sufficient to get the desired plot. Also, do note that you can also use Latex commands here on stack just like you did while writing your paper on any latex editor. No need to upload full image.

Comment: @codepbr, Thanks please check the equations and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot $dp/dx$ we can use `Module` as follows

```
dpdx[xe_, ye_, e_] := Module[{x = xe, yc = ye, q = -1.5, M = 0.3,
   \[Alpha] = 0.2, n = 0.5, \[Theta] = 0.5, 
   We = 0.02, \[Delta] = 0.0006}, h = 1 + e Cos[2  \[Pi]  x]; 
  m = M^2  Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
  eq = {psi''[y] == u[y], 
    D[(1 + n (We u[y] - 1)) u[y], y, y] - m u[y] == 0}; 
  bc = {psi[0] == 0, u[0] == 0, 
    psi'[h] == -1 - 2 Pi e \[Alpha] \[Delta] Cos[2 Pi x], 
    psi[h] == q - 1};
  px = NDSolveValue[Join[eq, bc], 
    D[(1 + n  (We  u[y] - 1))  u[y], y] - m  (psi'[y] + 1), {y, 0, h},
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 5,
     PrecisionGoal -> 4]; px /. y -> yc]
```

Visualization

```
ini = {.1, .3, .5, .6};

lst = Table[Table[{x, dpdx[x, 0, eps]}, {x, 0, 1, .02}], {eps, ini}]

ListLinePlot[lst, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"\[Epsilon] =", eps}], {eps, ini}], 
 PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "dp/dx"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Many thanks, it works. !!!!!

Comment: @MuhammadMubashirBhatti don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem to give due credits to Alex :)

Comment: @codebpr. Yes, I just did it.